# Is Chrome desktopCapture API working on Linux

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to run Desktop Capture Example on Chrome not stable build Version 34.0.1809.0 dev aura but it fails.

Reason is that chrome.desktopCapture is undefined but according to docs it should work :

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture.html

any ideas if it is me doing sth wrong or is this a bug in Chrome?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.  Did you find a resolution?

Comment: @LanceCaraccioli Unfortunately not.

Comment: See http://crbug.com/310329

Comment: @wonglik this works for me now in chrome 35

Comment: @LanceCaraccioli , yes that's true. I guess problem was that I was using Chromium where it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a permission on your manifest file to enable it.

```
{
    "permissions": ["desktopCapture"],
    ...
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this is the issue?

Comment: @Xan I thought at first that it could be a permissions in manifest.js but I'm wrong, I have just tried it and it is still cannot get the streamId on the callback function. As of now I don't have any idea why.

If anybody got an idea please let us know I am also very interested on this new feature.

Answer (score 0):

As some people already noticed it does work now in Chrome 35.

I guess my problem was that I was trying to run it in Chromium which was causing problems.